# How to display Grade of Student in the Subject Using Spring Data Jpa @ManyToMany with 3 tables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, hql

Hello I want to display the grade of the student in the specific subject, I want to combine the 3 tables student, subject and grade tables into a student_subject_grade and want it to be returned like this:

```
      "studentList": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "username": "IN",
                "password": "admin",
                "fullName": "Depp",
                "email": "i@live.com",
                "subjectList": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Programim 1",
                    
                        "markList": [
                            {
                               
                                "mark": 10,
                                "description": "Excellent"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Programim 2",
                     
                        "markList": [
                            {
                              
                                "mark": 9,
                                "description": "Very Good"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Calculus",
                      
                        "markList": [
                            {
                              
                                "mark": 8,
                                "description": "Good"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Discrete mathematics",
                    
                        "markList": [
                            {
                          
                                "mark": 7,
                                "description": "Well"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Here is the database schema:
[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsL4i.png)

**Here are the models:**

Student Model:

```
package springuniversity.Model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;



@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    //kjo column name duhet ta ket emrin ekzakt si eshte ne databaze emri i kolones perndryshe nuk punon si duhet dhe mund te krijoen kolona te reja ne tabele
    @Column(name="user_id")
    @JsonProperty
    private Integer user_id;

    @Column(name="username")
    @JsonProperty
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="fullname")
    @JsonProperty
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name="email")
    @JsonProperty
    private String email;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "student_subject", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonProperty
    private List<Subject> subjectList;


    public Student()
    {

    }


    public Student(int id, String username, String password, String fullName, String email, List<Subject> subjectList) {
        super();
        this.user_id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
        this.subjectList=subjectList;
    }




    public String getId() {
        return String.valueOf(user_id);
    }

    public void setId(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Subject> getSubjectList() {
        return subjectList;
    }

    public void setSubjectList(List<Subject> subjectList) {
        this.subjectList = subjectList;
    }





}
```

**
Here is the Subject Model:**

```
package springuniversity.Model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="Subject")
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    @JsonProperty
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "student_subject_marks", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id",   referencedColumnName = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@JsonProperty
private List<Subject> markList;



    public Subject() {
        this.id = id;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public  void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }



     public List<Subject> getMarkList() {
        return markList;
     }

     public void setMarkList(List<Subject> markList) {
    this.markList = markList;
      }





}
```

**Grade Model:**

```
package springuniversity.Model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="StudentMark")
public class StudentMark {

    @Id
    private int grade_id;

    @Column(name="mark")
    private int mark;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;



    public int getGrade_id() {
        return grade_id;
    }

    public void setGrade_id(int grade_id) {
        this.grade_id = grade_id;
    }

    public int getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(int mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

  

}
```

What I've tried so far is to create a List markList in the subject Model, the problem is I don't know how to map 3 foreign keys with spring data jpa or HQL, so far I just managed to display the subjects of the student with 2 foreign keys, how should this kind of problem be approached, I've struggled to find articles that explain this kind of topic properly that's why I asked this question.

Comment: There might be a first problem in your `Subject` class : `private List<Subject> markList`. Shouldn't it be a `List<StudentMark> markList`.

Comment: Yes you are right, my mistake but I still don't know how to map with 3 foreign keys.